# Display website in background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Alright, this is a little hard to explain but please bear with me!

I want to create a games website intended to be used secretly at school based on the idea of this website: http://nyanit.com/

If you have not already seen it yourself you type a link in the text box. Lets say we put in www.google.com. It generates a link something like http://nyanit.com/www.google.com.
Upon visiting that link you'll see the normal website but with nyan cat running across the screen.

I would like to do that same process, except instead of a cat a Facebook type popup like the ones you would see if you viewed a picture. You know, something that does not open a new tab or browser  simply an element on screen that can be hidden. Then I want to have the games website displayed inside there (I will be able to do this with no issues as I have done it before).

What I would like to know is: **how can I overlay my custom popup over a pre-existing website such as Google just like nyanit.com does it?**
--And not just Google, I'm looking for the same concept as Nyanit.com. A user may enter any website they wish. 

Edit: If it's not too much trouble try to keep suggestions IE compatible :)

Comment: Note that this websites doesn't work in webkit and firefox.

Answer (score 0):

One possible method is to have an iframe that covers the entire screen and loads in the website of your choice, then you have your actual game content in elements with a higher `z-index`.

Comment: This is actually what nyanit does :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use another div tag, and set it 100% body's height and width , and with position:absolute; display:none. when the event comes, you set the div a higher z-index,and display:block. then fill the div with the content you get. innerHTML will do that for you.
 I think it's a method to your question.

Good Luck!